# javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found angular 1.5

Tags: java, angularjs, http, web, jersey

i have this client angular 1.5 code

```
    var getGroupForUser = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(env.domain+'/Voices/authorize').then(
            function successCallback(response) {


                // self.isAdOps = response.data.;

                deferred.resolve(response.data);

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response.data.errorMsg);
                self.isAdOps = true;
                deferred.reject("data: "+response.data+" code:"+response.status+" "+response.statusText+", please look at the web console");
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

and this jersey java code on the server:

```
@Path("/Voices")
public class VoicesOperation {

    @Path("/search")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public List<VoiceUi> search(@QueryParam("q") String searchTerm) throws Exception {...
}


    @Path("/authorize")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public String authorize() {

        logger.info("in voicesOperation - authorization");
        logger.error("checking error log ==== in voicesOperation - authorization");
```

However i get in the server an error:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
```

what am i missing?

Comment: What url you are using for testing?

Comment: `env.domain+'/Voices/authorize'` -> `http://localhost:8860/Elton/Voices/authorize`

Comment: Does this url return value in the browser? Are you sure this is exactly the url the angular client is using?

Comment: Did you check by using directly `http://localhost:8860/Elton/Voices/authorize` from a internet browser?  Also print `env.domain+'/Voices/authorize'` and check whether url is correct or not. I believe `/Elton` you have declared in your web.xml file

Comment: @AbhijitPritam

I have tried same `http://localhost:8860/Elton/Voices/authorize` in the browser and same exception, but when i try `http://localhost:8860/Elton/Voices/seach` it works ok.

Comment: I think you need to put some signature in `authorize()` otherwise I did not see any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your like below and try:-

```
public String authorize(@Context UriInfo info) {
    .
    .
 }
```